# Why would you check whether the result of bitwise AND is equal to one of the values?

Tags: c++, c

I have just found a code where "bitwise and" is done, but unable to understand the logic clearly.

```
if( (value1 & value2 ) == value2)
{
    //Some code.
}
```

I know that the binary bit by bit AND operation is done on the variables.
But my question is if "bitwise and" between "value1" and "value2" yields "value2", what information am I supposed to deduce regarding the values?

Comment: That's probably a typo, since it's equivalent to `value1 & (value2 == value2)`.  Which is `value1 & true`.

Comment: `value1 & value2 == value2` checks that `value2`s  pattern is matched in `value1` completely unclear what's unclear in that statement.

Comment: Are there some brackets in that code that you didn't show? Is the code just that or is there more, because you should be able to see from the context what it's doing.

Comment: I just edited my question. In fact I was missing the paranthesis enclosing value1 & value2.

Answer (score 5):

Since `==` has a higher precedence that `&`, the expression is effectively:

```
(value1 & (value2 == value2))
```

The inner expression will always evaluate to true, so the numeric value will be 1.  Then you're left with `value1 & 1` which in boolean context tests if the least significant bit is set.

That's probably not what was intended, however.  It most likely was meant to be:

```
((value1 & value2) == value2)
```

The first part returns a value that has only the bits set that were set in both `value1` and `value2`.  Then it compares that value for equality against `value2`.

So that expression evaluates to true if the bits set in `value1` are a superset of the bits set in `value2`.  This could be useful if for example your variable contains a set of boolean flags and you want to know if a particular set of flags are enabled.

Comment: Ha!  You just added what I was going to throw into a secondary answer.  Very thorough.

Comment: Which I doubt the original programmer meant.  I suspect the intent was `( ( value1 & value2 ) == value2 )`, which checks if all the bits set in `value2` are also set in `value1`.

Comment: "you want to know if a particular set of flags are enabled." - putting it more clearly: this tells you if **all** of the given flags are set; as opposed to `value1 & value2` which tells you if **any** of the given flags are set.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, yes I meant exactly what you wrote. It was my mistake while typing the question.

Answer (score 5):

That all of the tested value bits were set in the other value.

A few simple examples:

```
1111 & 1010 = 1010
1110 & 1010 = 1010
1010 & 1010 = 1010
0010 & 1010 = 0010
1000 & 1010 = 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the `value2` is both used as a mask and to check the actual value.

In case, `value1` has some other value than that of `value2` a straight comparison will fail.

If we're interested in only a certain part of the value, we have to first mask out the unnecessary bits and  then perform the comparison.

Suppose,

- `value1` has a value of `14` (binary `00001110`),
- `value2` has a value of `2`   (binary `00000010`)
- and we're interested only in checking the the value contained in the LSB and LSB +1 equals to the value held by `value2` or not

So, in that case, doing a

```
  if (value1 == value2)
```

will fail and will not serve our purpose. OTOH,

```
 if( (value1 & value2 ) == value2)
```

will be first masking out the other bit values from `value1` and then perform the comparison with `value2`, which will give us the desired result.

A wide use of this technique is seen in case of checking a *flag* value.

Answer (score 1):

That's the classical way to check if a group of flags is set in a bitfield.

```
enum FileAttributes {
    ReadOnly = 1,
    Archive = 2,
    System = 4,
    Hidden = 8
};

unsigned int requiredAttrs = System | Hidden;
if((GetFileAttributes(fileName) & requiredAttrs) == requiredAttrs) {
    ...
}
```

The `&` is used to mask out the attributes that we don't care about (for example, the file may be `ReadOnly`, but we don't care), the `==` checks if *all* the required attributes are there.